# Changing endianness on 3 byte integer

Tags: c, arrays, endianness

I am receiving a 3-byte integer, which I'm storing in an array. For now, assume the array is `unsigned char myarray[3]`

Normally, I would convert this into a standard `int` using:

```
int mynum = ((myarray[2] << 16) | (myarray[1] << 8) | (myarray[0]));
```

However, before I can do this, I need to convert the data from network to host byte ordering.

So, I change the above to (it comes in 0-1-2, but it's n to h, so 0-2-1 is what I want):

```
int mynum = ((myarray[1] << 16) | (myarray[2] << 8) | (myarray[0]));
```

However, this does not seem to work. For the life of me can't figure this out. I've looked at it so much that at this point I think I'm fried and just confusing myself. Is what I am doing correct? Is there a better way? Would the following work?

```
int mynum = ((myarray[2] << 16) | (myarray[1] << 8) | (myarray[0]));
int correctnum = ntohl(mynum);
```

Comment: What's the type of myarray?

Comment: Sorry, posted that. It's `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you receive the value in network ordering (that is big endian) you have this situation:

```
myarray[0] = most significant byte
myarray[1] = middle byte
myarray[2] = least significant byte
```

so this should work:

```
int result = (((int) myarray[0]) << 16) | (((int) myarray[1]) << 8) | ((int) myarray[2]);
```

Comment: no need to cast to `int` since all operations on type narrower than `long` will be automatically promoted to `int`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc : in my original answer i didn't perform the cast, but someone suggested the edit saying that in some compiler this could be necessary. I guess that it is more clear with the cast, but now i wonder: is the automatic cast defined by the specification or not?

Comment: Yes, search default type promotions and you'll have lots of answer http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4cb.html

Comment: "In particular, arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied. This conversion always preserves the value." http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternate idea. Why not just make it structured and make it explicit what you're doing. Some of the confusion you're having may be rooted in the "I'm storing in an array" premise. If instead, you defined

```
typedef struct {
    u8 highByte;
    u8 midByte;
    u8 lowByte;
} ThreeByteInt;
```

To turn it into an int, you just do

```
u32 ThreeByteTo32(ThreeByteInt *bytes) {
    return (bytes->highByte << 16) + (bytes->midByte << 8) + (bytes->lowByte);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside the ways of using strucures / unions with byte-size members you have two other ways

1. Using ntoh / hton and masking out the high byte of the 4-byte integer before or after
   the conversion with an bitwise and.
2. Doing the bitshift operations contained in other answers

At any rate you should not rely on side effects and shift data beyond the size of data type.
Shift by 16 is beyond the size of unsigned char and will cause problems depending on compiler, flags, platform endianess and byte order. So always do the proper cast before bitwise to make it work on any compiler / platform:

```
int result = (((int) myarray[0]) << 16) | (((int) myarray[1]) << 8) | ((int) myarray[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't just receive into the top 3 bytes of a 4-byte buffer? After that you could use `ntohl` which is just a byte swap instruction in most architectures. In some optimization levels it'll be faster than simple bitshifts and `or`

```
union
{
    int32_t val;
    unsigned char myarray[4];
} data;

memcpy(&data, buffer, 3);
data.myarray[3] = 0;
data.val = ntohl(data.val);
```

or in case you have copied it to the bottom 3 bytes then another shift is enough

```
memcpy(&data.myarray[1], buffer, 3);
data.myarray[0] = 0;
data.val = ntohl(data.val) >> 8; // or data.val = ntohl(data.val << 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char myarray[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
# if LITTLE_ENDIAN // you figure out a way to express this on your platform
    int mynum = (myarray[0] <<  0) | (myarray[1] <<  8) | (myarray[2] << 16);
# else
    int mynum = (myarray[0] << 16) | (myarray[1] <<  8) | (myarray[2] <<  0);
# endif
printf("%x\n", mynum);
```

That prints 30201 which I think is what you want.  The key is to realize that you have to shift the bytes differently per-platform: you can't easily use ntohl() because you don't know where to put the extra zero byte.

Comment: This is not true at all. The endianess of the processor has no effect on the ordering of the bytes in the buffer, nor on how you shift the bytes to form the aggregate. Also, if the bytes in `myarray` were received from the network, then the value should print as 10203.